# Making a simple linked list in C++

Tags: c++, string, linked-list, cin

```
struct Node{
    string val;
    Node* next;
};

Node* makeList ()
{
    string current;
    Node* n;
    Node* head= NULL;
    Node* temp = n;

    while(cin>>current && !cin.fail())
    {
        n = new Node;
        n->val = current;
        temp ->next = n;
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    n->next = NULL;

    return n;
}
```

I am trying to learn about linked lists, and this function makeList() is supposed to create and return a linked list using input from a list of strings. To be honest, I'm kind of lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are returning the last node of the linked list.. I think you should return the head and assign it to the first Node.

Secondly you are using cin.fail() for a string which I think should not be done. cin.fail() will work if there is a data mismatch and for string I think it is rare.

The function would look somewhat like:

```
Node* makeList ()
{
    string current;
    Node* n;
    Node* head= NULL;
    Node* temp = n;

    while(cin>>current && !cin.fail())
    {
        if(current == "0")
            break;
        n = new Node;
        n->val = current;
        temp ->next = n;
        temp = temp -> next;
        if(!head)
            head = n;
    }
    n->next = NULL;

    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since your `temp` represents the last element I would put it to NULL at the beginning (`nullptr` is more in the spirit of C++, so I'll use it in the text that comes).
After that in a `while` loop ,when you are adding a new element, you should write `n->next=nullptr`,since the pointer `next` of the new element(if you're always adding it to the back of the list) will always point to nullptr. In your implementation your new element `n` is always pointing to itself.Later on in your while loop you need to check if `head==nullptr`, if that's true than you should assign `head` to the new element that you made `head=n`. If `head` is not equal to `nullptr` then you need to add your element `n` to the back `temp->next=n`. An at the and of the loop you should assign the `n` element as last-`temp=n` (that has to be outside of the else block since it is done in both of the above mentioned cases).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid answers above all got some bugs...

```
Node *make_link_list_from_input(){
    string value;
    Node *head = nullptr;
    Node *current = nullptr;
    Node *last = nullptr;

    while (cin >> value){
        current = new Node();
        if(head== nullptr){
            head = current;
        }
        if(last!= nullptr){
            last->next=current;
        }
        last=current;
    }
    if(last != nullptr) {
        last->next = nullptr;
    }
    return head;
}
```